# How to use yield instead of print with scrapy selector and selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

```
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class FlipkartSpider(Spider):
    name = 'flipkarttrial1'
    allowed_domains = ['flipkart.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\xyz\\chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/womens-footwear/heels/pr?sid=osp,iko,6q1&otracker=nmenu_sub_Women_0_Heels')
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        prices = sel.xpath('//div/div[@class="_1vC4OE"]/text()').extract()
        for price in prices:
            print(price)

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Here the **scraper** prints the price but when I use yield, it throws an error. I want to save prices to csv file. How can I save the data using 'yield'?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: The yield statement is used in place of return statements in functions to create generators which are then used to cycle through the results of the function. I'm not sure how you expect yield to help you here, explaining that would allow people to provide solutions to your issue. Also what error was being thrown ?

Comment: I tried the code with self.driver.get(response.url)  but it still doesn't work. The browser(Chrome) opens but the url doesn't load. Could you provide a way to save the price data to a csv file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to `yield` a proper Python dict like below

I guess you cannot yield items from strat_requests so just do a dummy request and then yield items in parse method

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=“http://ip-api.com/json”, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\xyz\\chromedriver')
    self.driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/womens-footwear/heels/pr?sid=osp,iko,6q1&otracker=nmenu_sub_Women_0_Heels')
    sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
    prices = sel.xpath('//div/div[@class="_1vC4OE"]/text()').extract()
    for price in prices:
        yield {“price": price}
```

Comment: Show me your scrapy logs... and how did you run scraper? Did you run like ‘scrapy crawl spider -o out.csv’

Comment: @Umair you forgot the `yield` there: `yield {"price": price}`

Comment: Here's the error report in this image: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ClQHakubcHS5xJRkMmv94KiZWnmWhbZP/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: I cant open link, thats private. Please attach image in your question

Comment: try again... permission granted

Comment: Given that error message, the scheduler is trying to schedule the dict as a `request` (which would have the `dont_filter` property), rather than yielding it like an item. I can't say why this is happening but the scheduler shouldn't be trying to access `dont_filter` on a dict or `Item`

Comment: @pwinz I guess you cannot yield items from strat_requests so just do a dummy request and then yield items in parse method

Answer (score -1):

You can easily omit selenium and scrapy.Selector and just use the response in the parse method.

```
import scrapy

class FlipkartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'flipkarttrial1'
    allowed_domains = ['flipkart.com']


    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/womens-footwear/heels/pr?sid=osp,iko,6q1&otracker=nmenu_sub_Women_0_Heels'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        prices = response.xpath('//div/div[@class="_1vC4OE"]/text()').extract()
        for price in prices:
            yield {'price':price}
```

Then run it using `scrapy crawl flipkarttrial1 -o data.csv -t csv`

Edited: If you still want Selenium, you can use the python's csv module to write the csv file.

The `start_request` method must return a `scrapy.Request(url, callback)` object, then the callback method (in below code, the `parse` method is the callback) is the one doing the rest of the work.

```
class FlipkartSpider(Spider):
    name = 'flipkarttrial1'
    allowed_domains = ['flipkart.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.flipkart.com/womens-footwear/heels/pr?sid=osp,iko,6q1&otracker=nmenu_sub_Women_0_Heels']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\xyz\chromedriver')
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        prices = sel.xpath('//div/div[@class="_1vC4OE"]/text()').extract()

        output = open('output_data.csv', 'w')
        fieldnames = ['price']
        csv_file = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames)

        for price in prices:
            yield csv_file.writerow({fieldnames[0]: price})
```

Comment: Without Selenium, javascript doesn't execute and the results obtained in csv sheet and website are different. This was the reason for using selenium

Comment: I have updated the answer. Yes the page returned by the scrapy downloader middleware is just the original page source.

Comment: check the error log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8fbUDln010o-BzVwptX8ifJ-aMzJVqy/view?usp=drivesdk) with the updated answer